# Order By Minimum distance from getdate

Tags: sql, date, sql-order-by, date-range

I have this table

```
Id_User Id_Subscription Date_Expiration
1       1               2013-01-21
1       2               2013-01-28    
2       1               2013-01-15
2       2               2013-01-30
2       3               2013-01-31
```

I want to order users with min distance from getdate (regardless of Id_Subscription) order by distance desc. Example:

```
Position Id_User   Distance in day
1        2         7
2        1         2
```

I have tried to do that

> ```
> SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COALESCE(MIN(us.Date_Expiration), 
> CAST('2015-01-29 16:30:23.000' AS DATE)) DESC, us.id_user) AS Row, us.id_user
> FROM User_Subscription us
> GROUP BY a.Id_Anagrafica
> ```

but it's not correct.

Comment: i guess the last two row of table are duplicate? or they are required?

Comment: it's an error i've correct

Comment: I think userId (2) max distance should be 8 and I am not sure how you get userId(1) max distance 2. I think it should be 5?

Comment: Sorry i've made and error. I want Min distance from Date_Expiration order by distance desc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ABS` with `Datediff`, for example:

```
SELECT Row_number() 
         OVER( 
           ORDER BY Abs(Datediff(dd, Getdate(), Date_Expiration)) ASC, 
         us.id_user) AS Row, 
       us.id_user 
FROM   user_subscription us
```

To complete your question. I assume you want the maximum distance in days for each user. So you can use `PARTION BY` in the `OVER` clause, for example (not tested, with SQL-Server >= 2005):

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Position = Row_number() 
                             OVER( 
                               partition BY id_user 
                               ORDER BY Abs(Datediff(dd, Getdate(), 
                             date_expiration ) 
                             ) 
                             DESC), 
                id_user, 
                [Distance in day] = Abs(Datediff(dd, Getdate(), date_expiration) 
                                    ) 
         FROM   user_subscription) 
SELECT position, 
       id_user, 
       [distance in day] AS [Max Distance in day] 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  position = 1
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66a7f/6/0)

Comment: WHERE position =1 what mean?

Comment: @LuigiSaggese: That's the record for each user with the maximum distance from `GetDate` since `ORDER BY Abs(Datediff(dd, Getdate(), 
                             date_expiration)) 
                             DESC`.

Comment: Sorry i've made and error. I want Min distance from Date_Expiration order by distance desc

Comment: Here is [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66a7f/2). I think it is not working.

Comment: @Kaf: Thanks, i've missed the `FROM` clause in the select in the `CTE` ;) Edited my answer and added the sql-fiddle.

Comment: @LuigiSaggese: Added Kaf's Sql-Fiddle and changed `Order By ... DESC` to `... ASC`. Now i get the  desired result, although the name `"Max Distance in day"` is misleading now.

Comment: @TimSchmelter i have change column name. :-) You must use order by [distance in day] desc. But if i'd like to have a ranking position in result set?

Comment: @LuigiSaggese: You don't need to use the `WHERE` clause to constrain the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. Here is [Sql-fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66a7f/9)

```
select row_number() over(order by numberofdays desc) position, 
           Id_User, numberofdays 
from (
     select Id_User, abs(datediff(day, getdate(), Date_Expiration )) numberofdays,
            rank() over (partition by Id_User order by abs(datediff(day, getdate(),  Date_Expiration )) ) rnk
     from user_subscription
    ) A
where rnk = 1


--Results
POSITION    ID_USER NUMBEROFDAYS
1           2        7
2           1        2
```

Comment: Sorry i've made and error. I want Min distance from Date_Expiration order by distance desc. Check your answer.

Comment: @LuigiSaggese: Okay sorted. it gives what you need now.

Answer (score 0):

With following table structure

```
create table user1(id_user number,id_sub number,date_exp date);
```

Try this :

```
select row_number()   OVER (ORDER BY user1.id_user) position,id_user,MAX(date_exp)-MIN(date_exp) Max_Distance_in_day from user1 group by id_user;
```

with output:

```
| POSITION | ID_USER | MAX_DISTANCE_IN_DAY |
--------------------------------------------
|        1 |       1 |                   7 |
|        2 |       2 |                  16 |
```

Here's [fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bacac/25/6)

Comment: Sorry i've made and error. I want Min distance from Date_Expiration order by distance desc

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
       ROW_NUMBER() over (order by min(abs(datediff(d,date_expiration,getdate()))) desc) [rank]
       ,id_user
       ,min(abs(datediff(d,date_expiration,getdate()))) as distance
from User_Subscription
group by id_user`
```